# Elastic Beanstalk deployment times out and "Rate exceeded" error prevents viewing logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm in the process of migrating a `Django` app from `Heroku` to `Elastic Beanstalk`. Deploys were working and I was debugging issues to try to get the requirements.txt working then deploys stopped.

Now they will time out. The worst part of this is I'm unable to access logs, so I have no idea what's causing the issue.

Image of events:
[image]

When I try to access logs it either returns the error `An error occurred retrieving logs: Rate exceeded` or it will trigger the event `requestEnvironmentInfo is starting.` which itself will time out.

I'm not sure how you can move forward in debugging without access to the logs. I've cloned into a new environment and terminated the old one, but that didn't work. If you've encountered similar issues or know how to proceed please provide help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by terminating the main `EC2` instance and redeploying in `EB`. in a larger instance. In this case `small`.

Comment: Would be helpful for the command to do that, eb init doesn't promt instance size by default so...